# Limiting value of $L^2$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.  Let $x\in \Omega$.

Suppose I evaluate $f$ at points from some direction that approach $x$.  Similarly, suppose I evaluate $f$ at points from a different direction that approach $x$.

**Question:**  Will these two limits coincide almost everywhere?  I can't think of a counter example, and I'm not sure how to go about a proof...maybe use density of continuous functions in $L^2$?

**Edit:**  See the notes in the link below.  The sentence directly above equation (2.6) in these notes is perhaps a better explanation of what I'm trying to establish (the $[\cdot]$ operator is defined in subsection 2.1).

http://www.cimpa-icpam.org/archivesecoles/20140204154528/dgfem.pdf

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why the limits should exists, let alone be equal...

Comment: "Suppose I evaluate $f$"  You cannot evaluate an element of $L^2$ pointwise and expect a well-defined result.  Review the definition of $L^p$ spaces.  Even approaching points through entire smooth curves does not make sense, because smooth curves still have zero Lebesgue $2$-measure.

Comment: @guest  Rudin in Real and Complex Analysis defines $L^p$ as a space of bona fide functions. Same thing here.: http://www.math.uh.edu/~dlabate/PagesfromAnalysis.pdf  It's $L^p$ the metric space that requires equivalence classes.

Comment: @zhw. fair enough, but since the question did mention "density of continuous functions in $L^2$" I think he has the metric in mind.

Comment: Take the indicator function on the rationals. The limits don't exist at any point, in either direction.

Comment: Hmm, I see that my question as is does not make sense.  What if instead of $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ I request $f\in H^2(\Omega)$?